# How to change the desktop environment from lxqt to lxde

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, desktop-environments, lxde, lxqt

I am running Lubuntu 18.04 on my computer. I was curious and accidentally changed the desktop environment from lxde to lxqt in the login screen. I don't have lxqt installed. It shows me a black screen . Please help me to change back to lxde

Comment: Log out or reboot and select lxde at the login just like you selected lxqt

Comment: I filed a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1786602. Voting to close as such.

Answer (score 4):

There shouldn't be any `lxqt` session in the login screen unless you've done something which you haven't reported.

The default choices are:

- Lubuntu
- Lubuntu Qt session
- Openbox

[image: Default login choices]

The contents of `/usr/share/xsessions/QLubuntu.desktop` are:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Lubuntu Qt session
Comment=A specific Lubuntu session using Qt
Exec=/usr/bin/startlxqt
Type=Application
```

Running

```
locate startlxqt
```

comes up empty.

And when a user chooses to login with `Lubuntu Qt session`, the following window pops up:

[image: startlxqt not found]

The only option is to click `Okay` after which the system crashes.

In my opinion, `Lubuntu Qt session` shouldn't have been present at all. It just doesn't work. You most probably will have to reboot as suggested by [Panther in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064212/how-to-change-the-desktop-environment-from-lxqt-to-lxde#comment1743028_1064212) to your question.

When you do reboot and reach the login screen, carefully click on the image to the left of `en_US` (or whatever language choice you have) and carefully choose `Lubuntu` because if you don't the likelihood is that you'll again end up with the `Lubuntu Qt session` because the last choice is remembered.

Once you're safely logged in, if you want to ensure you never accidentally click on the `Lubuntu Qt session` again, open your terminal and run the following commands:

```
cd /usr/share/xesssions
sudo rm QLubuntu.desktop
```

The next time you login, you won't see  `Lubuntu Qt session` as an option.

[image: Lubuntu Qt session removed]

---

**Update**
This issue has been addressed and a fix is committed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1786602/comments/2

Comment: I have used lxqt on fedora for 2 years, I like it more than lxde, but I am not familiar lubuntu

Comment: I'm using it on Lubuntu 18.10. It's decent there. But not on Lubuntu 18.04. I have the same experience as OP :(

Comment: @Panther, I've edited the answer to provide the contents of `QLubuntu.desktop` which is the problematic one. It tries to execute `/usr/bin/startlxqt` which does not exist.